# Is there any reason why weapons use increasing D6 numbers instead of size?

Tags: d6-system

I'm currently wondering a bit about vehicle and bigger weapons in D6.
Aside from a few examples in open space d6 and star wars I've seen only examples where vehicle weapons have ever growing amounts of dice but still count as size 0 weapons.

Thus there I began to wonder if there is any reason for that.

If we take a side winder for example I've seen it as 12D6, but thought there why not only 3-4d6 and an appropriate size of 9+. Similar for example for a nuclear blast or an antimatter blast. Also similarily for a bazooka. Even though it is held by humans it is made to fight vehicles.

So am I overlooking here something? Thus is there any special reason I've overseen so far for why this most D6 derivates do use more and more D6 for combating higher size beings/vehicles instead of just adding "size" to the weapon/weapons effect ?

*To make it a bit more clear I'm looking mainly there ruleswise if there is any explanation to there (designwise it could be to reduce confusion among players,... that is clear although also confusing because it means up to 20 dices to be rolled, but maybe I'm overlooking here something rules wise or if not designwise)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because scale *also* modifies the difficulty to hit your target.

Your hypothetical Giant Sidewinder might do similar damage, but it becomes much more difficult to hit your target with. You can adjust for that, but then you have a much more complicated entry.

From there, it probably boils down to design decisions:

- Having a consistent scale modifier against each target, instead of a scale modifier for each individual weapon.
- Make powerful effects look powerful, without having to worry about the player missing the scale/size description.
- Allow similarly sized entities to ignore the scale system and just fight with their printed stats.